# Error accessing packages placed in sys.path array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a custom package which has a single function.

On adding the path of this module to the sys.path array, I am unable to access it.
How to access package once its path has been added to the sys.path array object ?

[Here's the screenshot of the code I have typed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvrIK.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file name `hello_world.py` and you already add the path to the folder containing that file to system path, you can import it directly without the folder's name, meaning:

```
import hello_word
```